# Calling a function with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm not sure how to explain this completely, but I hope this will make sense.

I have a function that I've made that calculates the remaining amount to spend to qualify for free delivery when the basket value total falls within certain thresholds.

The basket value is updated with AJAX every time a product is added to the basket.

The add to basket button appears in an AJAX generated modal.

I need my function to be called on every page refresh and also every time a product is added to the basket when the AJAX generated add to basket button is clicked. I'm trying to do all of this with the below, but it doesn't seem to work correctly. One of the problems is that the event fires multiple times when the add to basket button is clicked and another is that the basket total is updated after the event and so the total isn't calculated correctly.

Can anyone explain how I would tidy all off this up?

```
function totalBag() {
   var standardDeliveryLow = 49.99;
   var standardDeliveryHigh = 64.99;
   var expressDeliveryLow = 65.00;
   var expressDeliveryHigh = 99.99;
   var bagValue = $('#basket-value').text();
   var bagTotal = Number(bagValue.replace(/[^0-9\.-]+/g,""));

   if (bagTotal >= standardDeliveryLow && bagTotal <= standardDeliveryHigh) {
       var standardDifference = parseFloat(Math.round((standardDeliveryHigh - bagTotal) * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
       $('<div class="delivery-message"><p>£'+ standardDifference +' from standar delivery</p></div>').insertAfter('.breadcrumbs');
   } else if (bagTotal >= expressDeliveryLow && bagTotal <= expressDeliveryHigh) {
      var expressDifference = parseFloat(Math.round((expressDeliveryHigh - bagTotal) * 100) / 100).toFixed(2); 
      $('<div class="delivery-message"><p>£'+ expressDifference + ' from express delivery</p></div>').insertAfter('.breadcrumbs');
   } else {
     return false;
   }
}

$(document).on('ajaxSuccess', function(e) { 
  $('[name="AddItemToBasket"]').on('click', function() {
    $('body').bind('ajaxSuccess.custom', function() {
     totalBag();
     //alert('this works');
     $(this).unbind('ajaxSuccess');
  });
 });
});


totalBag();
```

Comment: "One of the problems is that the event fires multiple times when the add to basket button is clicked". This is because `$(document).on('click', function(e) { ` means that every time anyone clicks _anywhere_ on the page, it adds another "click" event handler to the AddItemToBasket element, by running that code again. So you could have dozens of handlers if you're not careful. Setting an event handler on an element doesn't remove the ones previously defined, it just keeps on adding more. Did you mean `$(document).ready(function() { ` by any chance (i.e. run this code once when the DOM loads)?

Comment: Also .bind() was superseded by .on() (which you've used elsewhere) in jQuery 1.7, years ago, and deprecated in 3.0. There is no good reason to use it, really. http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: It's in a document ready function, although I've not included that, apologies for teh confusion.

Comment: In that case you can just remove `$(document).on('click', function(e) {` entirely, I think.

Comment: On click of the add button, is there a Ajax call?? Or the only Ajax call is to display the modal?

Comment: yes @KeerthiKumarP there is a Ajax call - it updates the basket value

Comment: Post HTML as well, I can't keep track of what is clicked or what could be clicked or what shouldn't be clicked.

Comment: I am still trying to understand the line `the basket total is updated after the event and so the total isn't calculated correctly`. Can you elaborate more on it? Possible to post the ajax callback that is getting executed on click of Add to Basket button?

Comment: The best I can do is show you the page I am working with, which is [link](https://www.riverisland.com/c/men/shoes-and-boots?icid=mhp/prm2/shoes-and-boots/cat ) . I'm trying to use the function on this page.

Comment: I'm basically using a multi variant testing tool to add javascript to the existing page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Have fixed the issue where text was duplicating. Also have added comments for more understanding.

---

Had a check at the link you specified and tried the following modified code.

As per @ADyson, have removed the click event, which is fixing the multiple event firing.

Regarding your other problem, the total is updated after the event, yes the HTML is getting updated after the ajaxSuccess is triggered. Hence have used the ajaxSuccess event itself to get the basket amount and use it in totalBag fn.

It seems to be working. Kindly confirm:

```
//Adding empty div so that we can just update the value later
$(document).on('ready', function(){
    $('<div class="delivery-message"></div>').insertAfter('.breadcrumbs');
})

function totalBag(bagTotal) {
   var standardDeliveryLow = 49.99;
   var standardDeliveryHigh = 64.99;
   var expressDeliveryLow = 65.00;
   var expressDeliveryHigh = 99.99;
   //var bagValue = $('#basket-value').text();
   //var bagTotal = Number(bagValue.replace(/[^0-9\.-]+/g,""));

   //Using a variable to store the calculated amount with text
   var innerHTML = "";
   if (bagTotal >= standardDeliveryLow && bagTotal <= standardDeliveryHigh) {
       var standardDifference = parseFloat(Math.round((standardDeliveryHigh - bagTotal) * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
       innerHTML= "<p>£"+ standardDifference +" from standar delivery</p>";
   } else if (bagTotal >= expressDeliveryLow && bagTotal <= expressDeliveryHigh) {
      var expressDifference = parseFloat(Math.round((expressDeliveryHigh - bagTotal) * 100) / 100).toFixed(2); 
      innerHTML= "<p>£"+ expressDifference +" from express delivery</p>";
   } else {
     return false;
   }
   //Updating the placeholder with new contents
   $(".delivery-message").html(innerHTML);
}

//Gets triggered after every Ajax Success.
//e -> event object, xhr -> The Ajax object which has request and response details, 
//settings -> The settings we used to trigger Ajax, including the request URL
$(document).on('ajaxSuccess', function(e, xhr, settings) { 
    //Checking if the request is of Adding Item to Basket
    if(settings.url.indexOf("AddItemToBasket") !== -1){
        //Getting the response and parsing it
        var resp = xhr.responseText;
        var respObj = JSON.parse(resp);
        //Checking if response is success i.e., item added to cart successfully
        if(respObj.success){
            //Getting the updated Basket value and calling totalBag
            var bagTotal = respObj.basket.subTotal;
            totalBag(bagTotal); 
        }       
    }

});
totalBag(0);
```

Comment: this solution worked perfectly. Thank you very much! I've seen the ajaxSuccess callback work like this, but I couldn't understand it or how to apply it to my situ. If you can explain it I'd be very grateful. Thanks again!

Comment: Although, it performs the event every time an item is added, which mean it inserts the jquery in to the DOM each time. Is there a way to have it only update the same total each time it is fired?

Comment: Yup..it should be possible. On document ready, add the delivery message div. And on totalBag call, update the contents alone. Try and let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: @determined-to-learn Have fixed the issue where text was duplicating. Also have added comments for more understanding.

Comment: Again, this works perfectly, and the comments have helped a lot to understand it. Thanks for all your work!